# почему RESTfull сервис обязан использовать определенные запросы

Tags: rest

Сижу курю тему про REST, SOAP, RPC и их сравнения. Основной камень в огород REST это обязанность RESTfull приложений использовать для действий определенные глаголы для определенных действий CRUD (GEt, Put...).

А где в REST это сказано? Я знаю что REST это концепция и набор ограничений, а не протокол. И что GET, PUT это глаголы HTTP. И то что под RESTfull службой чаще всего подразумевают службу использующую HTTP, которая соответствует по своей структуре всем ограничениям REST. Но в описании REST (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) я не вижу ограничения диктующего что для определенных действий CRUD необходимо использовать определенные глаголы HTTP. (я понимаю, что оно там есть, просто для меня не понятно какое конкретно).

Answer (score 1):

Просто, так принято. Можно воспринимать как рекомендацию.

Comment: А если я буду использовать только POST для всех действий, а подробности задам в теле сообщения (например реализую XML-RPC), то это уже не REST? Какое ограничение я нарушил? А если это все еще REST, почему тогда сравнивают REST и   XML-RPC или SOAP

Comment: @Dmitrii да, это уже не REST-овый подход.